# Getting data from input to use as object in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm not sure of how to create an event listener that takes text from an input and sends the input to a variable on javascript. Then, the variable will produce another output. For example, if you type "f" (forward) on the text box, the variable will have to make that input equal to a number.

```
<input type="text" id="textinput">
</input>
<button type="button" onclick="console()" id="click">Try it</button>

var console = function() {
  $("#textinput").val();
  if (console == "hi") {
    alert("#text input was also hi");
  }
}
```

Comment: Here is a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jasonwilczak/j6nf2c4z/) of your issue

Comment: I would avoid using "console" as a variable or function name, as there is already a "console" object in javascript - i.e. console.log()

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var console = function() {
    $("#textinput").val();
    if (console == "hi") {alert("#text input was also hi")}
}
```

`console` is a function, you can't test it against "hi". You want to retrieve the value of the textbox using another variable.
You could also try to use the onKeyUp event directly on the textbox to avoid pushing the button everytime you modify the input.

Try :

```
$("#click").click(function() {
  var value = $("#textinput").val();

   if (value == "hi") {alert("#text input was also hi")} 
});
```

And remove the `onclick` on the button.

http://jsfiddle.net/j6nf2c4z/4/

Comment: Take a look at the fiddle.

Comment: Thanks Michael, something really weird is happening. It works on your fiddle and I literally copy and pasted it in mine and it wouldn't work. Still, I get how the code would work ok, thanks so much!

Comment: Ok, found the reason, I had the tab "no library, pure javascript", instead of "jQuery". It's what happens when you are a beginner! Thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

onkeypress will do the job, but you'll have to type something after hi, or may be a single space.

```
<!DOCTYPE>

<html>
<head>
<script src="http://lotrucks.in/js/jquery-1.11.2.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">


function cons() {

    var console = $("#textinput").val();
    if (console == "hi") {alert("#text input was also hi")}
}

</script>
</head>


<body>
<input type="text" id="textinput" onkeypress="cons();" />

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you, it looks correct, but the alert won't pop up when I type "hi" and click

Comment: Not click, just type, I meant, sorry

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest removing the onclick attribute setter in html and use the jQuery click method.  Then, you can just get the value and do your conditional logic (here is a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jasonwilczak/j6nf2c4z/3/))

Javascript:

```
$('#click').click(function () {
    var inputVal = $("#textinput").val();
    if (inputVal == "hi") {
        alert("#text input was also hi");
    }
    else
    {
     alert('input was ' + inputVal);   
    }
});
```

HTML (no inline click event setter and you do not need the type attribute):

```
<input type="text" id="textinput">
</input>
<button id="click">Try it</button>
```

Comment: Thanks, I did try the click method before, but no luck. I'm not sure of what's happening

Comment: The fiddle is working good, are you wrapping your click function in a $(document).ready(function(){}); ?

Comment: Sorry Jason, I didn't mention it to you. It is, the problem was to select the jQuery library on jsfiddle. Thanks!